# Cursor in Mysql not working in Mysql 5.57

Tags: mysql, sql

Cursor in Mysql not working in Mysql 5.57

I converted SQL query into MySQL query, SQL query give me records, but in Mysql query is doesn't provide any records and neither give any error

//Following is my SQL query

```
USE [Trackdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetRecords]    Script Date: 06-11-2019 09:48:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRecords]
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(15)

create table #TempHotel
(
    CatID Varchar(50), 
    Cnt INT, 
    Date Date
)

create table #TempRestaurant
(
    CatID Varchar(50), 
    Cnt INT, 
    Date Date
)

DECLARE Track_CURSOR CURSOR  
LOCAL  FORWARD_ONLY  FOR  
SELECT Distinct(Convert(date,ms_date)) FROM tbltrackingrtt WHERE ms_date > '2017-11-01' AND heirarchy LIKE '%*145*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 145
OPEN Track_CURSOR  
    FETCH NEXT FROM Track_CURSOR INTO  @Date
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    --PRINT  'EMP_ID: ' + @Date --+  '  EMP_NAME '+@EMP_NAME +'  EMP_SALARY '  +CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@EMP_SALARY)  +  '  EMP_CITY ' +@EMP_CITY  

    INSERT INTO #TempHotel
    SELECT TOP 100 Category AS CatID, Count(id) Cnt, convert(Date,ms_date) Date FROM tbltrackingrtt 
    WHERE heirarchy LIKE '%*145*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 145 AND CONVERT(DATE,ms_date) = @Date
    GROUP BY Category, convert(Date,ms_date)
    ORDER BY convert(Date,ms_date) ASC, Count(id) DESC

    INSERT INTO #TempRestaurant
    SELECT TOP 100 Category AS CatID, Count(id) Cnt, convert(Date,ms_date) Date FROM tbltrackingrtt 
    WHERE heirarchy LIKE '%*169*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 169 AND CONVERT(DATE,ms_date) = @Date
    GROUP BY Category, convert(Date,ms_date)
    ORDER BY convert(Date,ms_date) ASC, Count(id) DESC

    FETCH NEXT FROM Track_CURSOR INTO @Date

END  
SELECT * FROM #TempHotel
SELECT * FROM #TempRestaurant

CLOSE Track_CURSOR  
DEALLOCATE Track_CURSOR 

DROP table #TempHotel
DROP table #TempRestaurant

END
```

// Following is my Mysql query

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetRecords`()
BEGIN
DECLARE NOT_FOUND INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_Date VARCHAR(15);

DECLARE Track_CURSOR 
CURSOR FOR
SELECT Distinct CAST(ms_date as Date) FROM tbltrackingrtt WHERE ms_date > '2017-11-01' AND heirarchy LIKE '%*145*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 145;
create temporary table TempHotel
(
    CatID Varchar(50), 
    Cnt INT, 
    Date Date
);

create temporary table TempRestaurant
(
    CatID Varchar(50), 
    Cnt INT, 
    Date Date
);
OPEN Track_CURSOR;
   FETCH  Track_CURSOR INTO  v_Date;
WHILE NOT_FOUND = 0  
DO  
    -- PRINT  'EMP_ID: ' + @Date --+  '  EMP_NAME '+@EMP_NAME +'  EMP_SALARY '  +CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@EMP_SALARY)  +  '  EMP_CITY ' +@EMP_CITY  

    INSERT INTO TempHotel
    SELECT Category AS CatID, Count(id) Cnt, CAST(ms_date as Date) as Date FROM tbltrackingrtt 
    WHERE heirarchy LIKE '%*145*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 145 AND CAST(ms_date as Date) = v_Date
    GROUP BY Category, CAST(ms_date as Date)
    ORDER BY CAST(ms_date as Date) ASC, Count(id) DESC LIMIT 100;

    select TempHotel;

    INSERT INTO TempRestaurant
    SELECT  Category AS CatID, Count(id) Cnt, CAST(ms_date as Date) as Date  FROM tbltrackingrtt 
    WHERE heirarchy LIKE '%*169*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 169 AND CAST(ms_date as Date) = v_Date
    GROUP BY Category, CAST(ms_date as Date)
    ORDER BY CAST(ms_date as Date) ASC, Count(id) DESC LIMIT 100;

    FETCH Track_CURSOR INTO v_Date;

END WHILE;  
SELECT * FROM TempHotel;
SELECT * FROM TempRestaurant

CLOSE;
DROP table TempHotel;
DROP table TempRestaurant;

END
```

Anyone help me on this, I don't what I am doing wrong here, is there is any problem in MySQL cursor

Comment: Correct the mysql version number 5.57 doesn't exists. https://dba.stackexchange.com is better forum for this question.  Try harder to find the error on creation or use. Welcome to SO.

Comment: still any solution

Comment: You don't have a handler in the procedure so does the code run and run forever?

Comment: Since there is at least one obvious syntax error in your code (`select TempHotel;` is invalid), you should get an error when you run your code. You are probably running your code without showing execution errors, while not getting a result due to the error. It's much easier to find errors if you show them. Maybe add how you run your code. E.g. in php, you may need to set options in order to display errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax error pointed out by @solarflare the only thing that appears to be wrong with this code is the lack of a handler you should review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/handler.html (which you should know about for error handling in mysql)

```
drop procedure if exists p;
drop temporary table if exists temphotel,temprestaurant;

drop table if exists tbltrackingrtt;
create table tbltrackingrtt 
(id int auto_increment primary key,ms_date date,heirarchy varchar(20),category int);

insert into tbltrackingrtt (ms_date,heirarchy,category) values
('2017-11-02','*145*',10), ('2017-11-02','*145*',10),
('2017-11-02','*169*',10), ('2017-11-02','*145*',10);

delimiter $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE p()
BEGIN
DECLARE NOT_FOUND INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_Date VARCHAR(15);

DECLARE Track_CURSOR 
CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Distinct CAST(ms_date as Date) 
    FROM tbltrackingrtt 
    WHERE ms_date > '2017-11-01' AND heirarchy LIKE '%*145*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 145;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET not_found = TRUE;

create temporary table TempHotel
(
    CatID Varchar(50), 
    Cnt INT, 
    Date Date
);

create temporary table TempRestaurant
(
    CatID Varchar(50), 
    Cnt INT, 
    Date Date
);
OPEN Track_CURSOR;
   FETCH  Track_CURSOR INTO  v_Date;
WHILE NOT_FOUND = 0  DO  
    -- PRINT  'EMP_ID: ' + @Date --+  '  EMP_NAME '+@EMP_NAME +'  EMP_SALARY '  +CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@EMP_SALARY)  +  '  EMP_CITY ' +@EMP_CITY  

    INSERT INTO TempHotel
    SELECT Category AS CatID, Count(id) Cnt, CAST(ms_date as Date) as Date 
     FROM tbltrackingrtt 
    WHERE heirarchy LIKE '%*145*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 145 AND CAST(ms_date as Date) = v_Date
    GROUP BY Category, CAST(ms_date as Date)
    ORDER BY CAST(ms_date as Date) ASC, Count(id) DESC LIMIT 100;

    select * from TempHotel;

    INSERT INTO TempRestaurant
    SELECT  Category AS CatID, Count(id) Cnt, CAST(ms_date as Date) as Date  
     FROM tbltrackingrtt 
    WHERE heirarchy LIKE '%*169*%' AND category <> 0 AND category <> 169 AND CAST(ms_date as Date) = v_Date
    GROUP BY Category, CAST(ms_date as Date)
    ORDER BY CAST(ms_date as Date) ASC, Count(id) DESC LIMIT 100;

    FETCH Track_CURSOR INTO v_Date;

END WHILE;  
SELECT * FROM TempHotel;
SELECT * FROM TempRestaurant

CLOSE;
DROP table TempHotel;
DROP table TempRestaurant;

END $$

delimiter ;

call p();

+-------+------+------------+
| CatID | Cnt  | Date       |
+-------+------+------------+
| 10    |    3 | 2017-11-02 |
+-------+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.27 sec)

+-------+------+------------+
| CatID | Cnt  | Date       |
+-------+------+------------+
| 10    |    3 | 2017-11-02 |
+-------+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.29 sec)

+-------+------+------------+
| CatID | Cnt  | Date       |
+-------+------+------------+
| 10    |    1 | 2017-11-02 |
+-------+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.30 sec)
```